# where Joomla content builder record storing table can be found?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have explored all table with prefix contentbuilder in joomla 3.1 database but the form records(i.e data entered in forms) are not present in any table. where as other form details like storages, views, form elements etc are showing there presence.

for view which i am testing is  for backend view. so kindly help me in finding out where content builder is storing data entered in forms.

forms i am using are content builder forms not breezing one.

Comment: you mean this extension? http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/18048

Comment: Ok I had a look at the database tables in the install.php....look for `#__contentbuilder_articles`

Comment: actually in content builder there is an option to disable/enable article building. by disabling it, it will only store data in some xyz table(the table which i am searching) but will not make articles from that data.   #__cb_article contains foreign key to articles table only. data of each forum element is not present there.

Comment: its content table. it is generating article for both enable and disble state of article creatortor but playing with its published and and un published state. and also in content table it is storing data as html text . . .

Comment: @Lodder make your comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at the database, you need to be looking for the `#__contentbuilder_articles` table

Answer (score 0):

Content Builder by default create a separate table for your records. Based on the name of you View. For example if you View name is Invoices, check database with the same name like #_invoices